# How to get parrent of object in session SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

```
class Project(DataBase):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    domain = Column(String, nullable=False)
    phrases = relationship("Phrase", backref='proj')

    def __init__(self, name, domain):
        self.name = name
        self.domain = domain


class Phrase(DataBase):
    __tablename__ = 'phrases'

    query_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    query_text = Column(String, nullable=False)
    project = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('projects.id'), nullable=False)
    enable = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)


    def __init__(self, query_text, project, city):
        self.query_text = query_text
        self.project = project
```

And I have a function:

```
def get_first_query():
    session = Session(bind=engine)
    q = session.query(Phrase).filter(Phrase.enable == True).first()
    session.close()

    return q
```

I want to get an object from table 2 and than get its parrent from first table:

```
session = Session(bind=engine) 
q = get_first_query()
print(q.proj)
```

It doesn't work and print this error:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance  is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of
>   attribute 'proj' cannot proceed

I can do this:

```
session = Session(bind=engine) 
q = get_first_query()
q_project = session.query(Project).filter(Project.id == q.project)
```

But it's a bad way.

Comment: The official language of SO is English. There is a [Russian-language version of SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: sorry, i try to retype it in english

Answer (score 0):

You can assess related object via `proj` attribute.

```
session.query(Phrase).filter(
    Phrase.enable == True
).first().proj
```

This way you'll hit database one additional time to get it so you'll need to open session again. To avoid additional queries you can use [joined load](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload):

```
session.query(Phrase).filter(
    Phrase.enable == True
).options(
    joinedload('proj')
).first().proj
```